# best solution for use access in project for database with security

Tags: c#, database, security, ms-access

best solution for use access in project for database with security 
i need to use access with 600 megabyte in my project and my problem is low  security
for example i can rename access database extension to increase security
and people don't use my database for other goals
i will not to use sql server for every one to use my application i need local file based database because my application is in CD password is more secure but with easy way can find it
i can use sql server compact but installation is very long and my customer said installation is very long

Comment: Your going to need to provide a little more info.

Comment: More info needed.  What type of database are you trying to lock down?  What type of application is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider SQL Server Compact. No one who uses your application will need to install anything since SSCE runs in your process. This way you get the superior database and security provided by SQL Server, without having to install SQL Server. SSCE still lets you use a local file as your database.

Comment: but install  sql server compact is very long

Comment: How well does SSCE edition integrate with Access?  Can you continue to use bound forms, etc?

Answer (score 1):

if you have 600 MB of data, it's better that use from another db like sql server or mysql.

if you want to use access, you can set a password for that and then in your connection string set your username and password.

Comment: but  i will not to use sql server for every one to use my application
i need local file based database because my application is in cd
 password is more secure but with easy way can find it